# Django CMS Previous link history

Tags: python, django, dynamic, content-management-system

I need to make a link, that directs me to the previous Page.

Now i did it with a `href="{% page_url 'xyz' %}"` but thats not dynamic and a really bad idea.

Does anyone knows how to make that dynamic like request the previous link?

Comment: found it out. the solution was -> a href="{{ request.META.HTTP_REFERER }}"

Comment: Please don't rely on http_referer - some browsers may not send it at all, and it can be easily spoofed, so the users can be tricked into clicking a malicious link.